# How to bypass `with_lock` block in RSpec

Tags: rspec

I have a code block that locks the database table for coupons before calling a method on it.

```
coupon.with_lock do
    apply_user_coupon!(coupon)
end
```

How do I test this? I pretty much don't care about the lock... I just want the test to proceed to the `apply_user_coupon` method but I don't know how to get around the `with_lock` portion of the test. How do I do this?

Note that the block does not take an argument.

Answer (score 4):

Within an `it` or `before` block, you could stub out the functionality and let the block actually run with [`:and_yield`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/yielding).

```
allow(coupon).to receive(:with_lock).and_yield
```

Comment: and yield what?

Comment: There are some blocks which do not care about what is yielded. This is perfect for those